# Add an image in title bar in a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

In this example, how can i add a small image side by side with the title?

http://jsfiddle.net/F9uR3/

anyone?
thanks.

```
<span class="dialog">English</span>

<div id="dialog" class="dialogBox" title="LessonSelected">
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/opening/cta.png" />
```

`.ui-dialog-content div {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/opening/cta.png) no-repeat  !important;
}`

```
$(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable:false,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Enrol": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(true);
            },
            "Cancel Enrol": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(false);
            }
        }
    });

$( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try like this one

```
$(function () {

$('#dialog').dialog({
    title: $('<img src="http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Google-logo-small.jpg" />'),
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "Enrol": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            choice(true);
        },
            "Cancel Enrol": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            choice(false);
        }
    }
});

$(".dialog").click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
  });
});
```

**try to scale the image first at size**

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/F9uR3/3/) with your example

Comment: Thank you so much @Sreekesh Okky, but if i want to customize the "Your title" how can i do that? for example, I want to put the text aligned with the image (vertical align center).

http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/F9uR3/3/

Comment: @PauloFrutuoso: Just add a span with class and customize. http://jsfiddle.net/F9uR3/5/